# How can I hide all these extraneous HUD elements that appear in multiplayer?

Tags: trackmania-2

I recently tried TrackMania 2, via the Stadium open beta, and having picked a multiplayer server at random (well, with low ping and space) I was presented with the following screen. The edges of my view crowded with boxes full of data that I have no interest in, visual noise to me, with a sprinkling of player names stuck to every car, that intermittently obstruct my view when driving.

[image: screenshot]

A quick visit to a few other servers gives me similar results, but often with different layouts. While single player is clean. It looks like 'Dedimania' (as can be seen in a header on a box to the left) is a server-side mod of some kind, and I can only assume it is responsible for the mess.

In short: **How do I get rid of all the boxes and player names in multiplayer?**
Essentially, I want the clean and minimal UI that I get in single player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Maniaplanet forum](http://forum.maniaplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=268&t=8487), you can use either <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> to remove many of the server-side panels.

If you don't care so much about split times, you can use <kbd>*</kbd> on the numpad to remove all of the UI.

Comment: Since the recent 2018 UI update, F7 opens some friend list feature. F12 doesn't seem to do anything. Any news?